# SQL Server 2008 sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server's

sp_send_dbmail
to distribute mail. Everything is working fine; BUT I tried to test a bad email address and it always reports success; and nothing is in the failed sent items table.

Will this procedure report IF the email isn't sent? Or is success just getting the mail to the exchange server?

Thanks in advance!